# change button text when input type = file box is filled

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have the following setup:

- When "SELECT" is clicked a file browser opens and a file is selected.
- The file path selected will be displayed in `readonly` text box
- Functionality of the "SELECT" file button changes to submit the file

I also want the text if the "SELECT" button to change to "UPLOAD" but only when a file is selected (when the text box is not empty).

I have tried to use `on-change` and `on-input` for the text box, but no success... Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Following is my code :

**html**

```
<div class="horizontal layout fileUploadContainer">
    <paper-button class="upload" id=uploadButton on-click="uploadButton">Select</paper-button>
    <input type="text" id="fileName" class="fileName" placeholder="File..." on-click="changeButton" on-change="changeButton"></input>
    <input type="file" class="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" on-change="newFile">
</div>
```

**css**

```
 .fileUpload {
    display: none;
  }

  .fileName {
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid var(--divider-color);
  }
```

**js**

```
uploadButton : function() {
      if(this.$.fileName.value == ""){
          this.openUpload();
      } 
      else {

      }

  },

  openUpload : function() {
      this.$.fileUpload.click();
  },

  changeButton : function() {
      this.$.uploadButton.innerHTML = "submit";
  },

  newFile : function(e) {
      this.$.fileName.value = this.$.fileUpload.value;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is an approach , not tested though :

```
 $('#file_button').click(function(){
     $(this)
         .text("Upload")
         .attr('type','submit');
  });
```

Comment: Any chance you could do it not in JQuery? Trying to avoid it at all costs :-/

Comment: sorry for that , you may follow Jsilvermist answer . Is that working for you  ? if yes , then accept the answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change event on the file input like:

```
newFile: function(e) {
  // Change fileName value to selected filename
  this.$.fileName.value = e.target.files[0].name;
  // Change uploadButton value
  this.$.uploadButton.value = 'Upload';
}
```

Alternatively, and in case the above example doesn't bind properly, instead of using a hidden input you could use:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'file';
input.onchange = function(e) {
  // Change fileName value to selected filename
  this.$.fileName.value = e.target.files[0].name;
  // Change uploadButton value
  this.$.uploadButton.value = 'Upload';
}.bind(this);
input.click();
```